# How to convert text area data into select list in forms?

Tags: 7, forms

I want to create a configurable select list in forms.To achieve this what I did is I have created a text area, in that I will enter values like:

```
HI|Hi
BYE|Bye
```

So, in form select options I have to use these values in a dropdown list. How can I achieve that. I am getting this text area data in form like below.Here I am getting data, but not displaying in the options.

```
$entityoptions = variable_get('entitydropdown');
```

I am getting the values as it is, but am not getting how can I assign these  values to `#options`. I did like below but its not displaying the values.

```
'#options' => $entityoptions,
```

Please help me to identify, where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can already make select lists with Drupal, out of the box. May we ask why you're trying to make something Drupal already does?

Comment: But I need conifgurable values. So only I am saving values in one admin panel text area, SO that whenever I want I can change values, and dynamicaly those values should display in form select options.

Comment: Kinda like what Webform does? https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Comment: Yes like that only,but I dont want to use any modules.I have created a custom form, so in that I want to assign these dynamic values from Texarea.

Comment: Can you help me that, how can I retrieve data from text area in an array. I used explode('|',  $entityoptions  ); It works but,its failing to identify end of the line and next line.

Comment: Use explode() at PHP_EOL. You'll have an array of each line entered, so like this: array(HI|Hi, BYE|Bye). Then loop through it, split each value at the pipe, and make your options array from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested in the comments, in answer format:

1. Use the explode() function on your string
2. Loop through the results and split each entry
3. Add the result to the options array you feed to the select box

Eg.

```
$options = array();
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $entityoptions);
foreach($lines as $line) {
  $line = explode('|', $line);
  $options[$line[0]] = $line[1];
}
```